# How can I change a buffer view in emacs to hide HTML tags

Tags: html, emacs, preview

Like any conscientious emacs user I edit blog posts with it all the time using "It's All Text". However I'm often inserting HTML hrefs into my text and when I come to do my final proof read they tend to get in the way. Is there a mode I can toggle into that will hide these elements?

More generally are there any pointers on how to write a mode that modifies the actual buffer view while leaving the buffer contents untouched? Or does this just involve magic hacking with font-lock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `html-mode` you can use `M-x sgml-tags-invisible` to hide/show tags.

You can also `C-c C-v` to run `browse-url-of-buffer`, which opens the current buffer (if `buffer-file-name` is not `nil`, that is, if it's a regular file) with your default browser.
This works fine enough even with partial html blocks (i.e. without `<html>`, `<body>` etc.).

Comment: One minor snag is when the tags are hidden the display formatting isn't updated (I'm using longlines-mode) leaving rather short looking lines. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you (1) directly write HTML when writing the blogpost or (2) do you use some form of wiki language for lists, tables, etc. For (1) you could have a look at [org-mode](http://www.orgmode.org) and convert to HTML after proof read with `org-export-region-as-html`. In the second case you could look out for some special wiki mode which might hide the links (like [markdown-mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/)).

Comment: I write plain text with the occasional href thrown in. I'll have to experiment with both suggested approaches.